# How to get index in each function with html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need index in each function which has class = `index`,

My desired result is `2` and `4` and `5`, it is come from `td` element base index.

How can I get `td`base indexing?

If you have opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

```js
$(".index").each(function(){
let index=$(this).index()+1
console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="index">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="index">4</td>
    <td class="index">5</td>
     <td>6</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: What results are you getting? Have you read the documentation for the `.index()` method to understand what it does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`$(this).index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) is returning the index of the element *relative to its parent* element.

The callback function for [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) already receives the index of the element in the collection of matches, so if you want the index relative to the table you have to change the selector to a more general one and check if the element matches your condition.

```js
$("td").each(function(idx) {
  if ($(this).is('.index')) {
    console.log(idx + 1)
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="index">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="index">4</td>
    <td class="index">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in vanilla JavaScript like so:

```js
let indices = document.querySelectorAll(".index");
console.log(Array.from(indices).map((i) => i.textContent));
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="index">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="index">4</td>
    <td class="index">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So, you grab all elements with class "index" with `document.querySelectorAll(".index")` then you convert them to an array so that you can map them and take their inner content with [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:
     `$(".index").each(function () {
         console.log($(this)[0].innerHTML);
      });`

it wiil make the index the same as the value of the td.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` function you can pass index and current html element  `$(".index").each(function(i, item)`

And you can get td content by `text()` method, `$(item).text()` will get current td text.

```
$(".index").each(function(i, item){
let index=$(item).text();
console.log(index);
});
```

```js
$(".index").each(function(i, item){
let index=$(item).text();
console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="index">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td class="index">4</td>
    <td class="index">5</td>
     <td>6</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use javascript and spread operator it more shorter.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll(".index")].map((item, index)=>{
  console.log(item.textContent);
});
```

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll(".index")].map((item, index)=>{
  console.log(item.textContent);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td class="index">2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="index">4</td>
    <td class="index">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```